# Angularjs Updating controller variable when using POST

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a div based on the results of $http POST. The POST request resolves as expected, but I am unable to update the controller variable UserCreatedFlag.
I'm pretty sure this is a scope issue, and I've read several articles on the topic, but I'm missing something.

```
<html ng-app="registeruser">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
(function()
{   var app = angular.module('registeruser', []);
app.controller('RegisterUserController', function ($scope, $http) 
{
    this.ActiveDiv = 5;
    this.UserCreatedFlag = 0; 
    this.CreateUser=function()
    {   
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/AjaxFunctions.php?Function=CreateUser',
        data: "",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {   if(response.data == "Success")
                    this.UserCreatedFlag = 1; 

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
        });
    };
});
})();
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="RegisterUserController as RegUserCtrl">

<div ng-show="RegUserCtrl.ActiveDiv === 5">
    <div >
        <button name="btnUserRevewSubmit" type="button" ng-click="RegUserCtrl.CreateUser()">Create User</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="RegUserCtrl.UserCreatedFlag === 1">
        Some Message
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try to use ng-if instead of ng-show? your message is always displayed ? i'm a bit lose iin that part

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is inside the `then` callback. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback