# Angularjs - Instantiate array from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am merely trying to populate an array from an $http request and display the results in a table. Using Firebug, it seems to me that the data is being retrieved properly. See pictures for results.
[image: DOM Results]

[image: Firebug Results]

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('ContactsController', function ($scope, $http)
    {   var self = this; //added after initial post. 
        this.contactList = [];
        this.InitiateContactList = function(arrayContacts) //this.InitiateContactList doesn't work?
    {   for(i = 0; i < arrayContacts.length; i++)
            this.contactList.push(arrayContacts[i]);
    };

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'someurl', //pseudoCode
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
        }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {   if(angular.isArray(response.data))
                {   //this.contactList = response.data; //is this working properly?
                    self.contactList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
                    //this.InitiateContactList(response.data);
                }
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
        });
    }); 

    app.controller('ActionsController', function ($scope, $http)
    {
    }); 

    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ActionsController as ActCtrl">

    <div ng-controller="ContactsController as ContactsCtrl">
    <table 
        <tr><th Email</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Frequency</th></tr>
    </table>
    <div ng-repeat="Contact in ContactsCtrl.contactList">
        <table  >
        <tr><td>{{Contact.Email}}</td><td>test name</td><td>{{Contact.Frequency}}</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
   </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this.contactList = angular.fromJson(response.data); seems to be working. The DOM array is populated as expected, but the ng-repeat doesn't seem to be working. I've done this procedure a couple other times in other contexts and it has worked as expected. What am I missing?

Update: The Batarang extension in Chrome shows the following:
[image: Batarang]

Is it normal to have the index 'Contact' showing like that?

Comment: You've been already told about `this` reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638445/angularjs-updating-controller-variable-when-using-post#comment62758052_37638445

I see incorrect usage of `this` here as well.

Comment: @Sergey Goliney. Thank you for your help. The issue was a combination of your suggestion and a correction on the server side. It's likely that the data wasn't formatted as JSON properly, because it works fine when using PHP mysqli_fetch_assoc but not mysqli_fetch_array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ContactsController, do this

```
var self = this;
```

Now use `self` instead of all `this` in your controller:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'someurl', //pseudoCode
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
}).then(function (response) {
    self.contactList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had tried that earlier. I added your suggestion again after the line declaring the contactList array. I still get the same behavior. DOM object is populated, but ng-repeat doesn't show anything. I even added some test code to print the index of the contactList for ng-repeat. It's like the ng-repeat loop isn't working. I'm assuming that contactList is an array of objects. Maybe angular is seeing it as an array of length one?

Comment: @PabloFrancesca Do you apply `ng-repeat` on `<table>` instead of `<tr>` intentionally?

Comment: Correction. I was wrong. Your suggestion now has the ng-repeat working, but the Contact.email and Contact.Frequency are not resolving.

Comment: I've tried the ng-repeat on both <tr> and the encapsulating </div>. They produce the same ng-repeat behavior as the initial code. This is as expected I think?.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.contactList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
```

In this instance, `this` refers to the function prototype of the anonymous callback function from the `then()` call. Be careful in Javascript when using the word `this` in many callbacks and such. Declare a variable, and assign the needed function prototype, and then reference that variable, instead of the reserved, ever-changing `this` keyword.